# bit shifting using verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx

Im using verilog language for my program using ISE 14.5, when I give input for example x=0.707 and simulate it in test bench, it gives me wrong output because it consider 0.707 as 1.
my question is how to handle fraction number in verilog?

Comment: Are you trying to multiply/divide it by two, or bit-shift the representation of the number?

Comment: Im not trying to multiply or divide it by two, rather this number 0.707 will further multiply by any number, As the test bench consider it "1" in case of 0.707 and "-1" in case of -0.707

Comment: So then what does bit-shifting have to do with it?

Comment: shift the bit according to the decimal point. but how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up Fixed Point Arithmetic to see how to handle fractional numbers.  Basically you define the LSB of your data as some binary sub-multiple of 1 (e.g. 1/2^11).  You can then do all your normal arithmetic using integer hardware without having to handle fractions.

You can also do mixed integer and fractions by defining a number system such as 12.8 where 12 bits will cover the integer part (up to 4095 in this example) and the 8 remaining bits define the fractional part to 1/255 resolution.

Calculations such as FFT are frequently done using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The subset of Verilog that you can put in hardware doesn't include floating point. You are expected to make up your own floating point logic, which is very complex.